# How do I know which "File Descriptor" stands for a TCP connection in Python?

Tags: python, tcp, file-descriptor, handle

In Linux the `lsof` command is very helpful for listing open files, giving e.g. this output:

```
~$ sudo lsof -a -i  -u root -c python
=======
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 1504835 root   19u  IPv4 57127166      0t0  TCP urkam.fritz.box:http->GMC-500-old.fritz.box:5098 (ESTABLISHED)
python3 1504835 root 1022u  IPv4 57108854      0t0  TCP urkam.fritz.box:http (LISTEN)
```

For me this `FD: 19u` is the bad guy, I want to know about using Python.

Of no help is `os.stat()` which delivers this:

```
os.stat_result(st_mode=49663, st_ino=57160758, st_dev=8, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0, st_atime=0, st_mtime=0, st_ctime=0)
```

If this has TCP info then I don't see it.

Any other way to get the info that lsof is obviously able to get?

The final solutions needs to work on Linux, Widows, Mac.

EDIT:

Some progress from using psutil:

```
import os, psutil
pnc = psutil.net_connections(kind="inet4") 
for p in pnc:
    print("fd: ", p.fd, "  raddr: ", p.raddr)
    os.close(p.fd)
```

It allows me to find the open TCP connections, and provides the file descriptors (fd). Then I can close those bad files with `os.close(fd)`. Tested in overnight run - works fine!

However, on Windows psutil finds all the right files, which is nice, but does not help, because fd is always ==-1 ! This means an invalid fd and I cannot close this file by `os.close(fd)`.

So this approach does NOT work on Windows.

Windows apparently uses a concept different from file descriptors, called handles in Windows lingo. My understanding is they could be closed just the same with `os.close(handle)`.

But where and how do I find those handles?

Comment: `lsof` is open source. Did you check how it does it?

Comment: No. Beyond my competency level. And besides, it does not run on Windows!